# how to select the string in sql?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way select string with something eg.

```
Input:
ID12 - Test0
ID13 - Test-Part1
Test1
PKA - Test2
```

to be

```
Output:
Test0
Test-Part1
Test-Part1
PKA - Test2
```

Comment: Please edit your Q it's not clear at all.

Comment: Do you want to drop all before '- ' if it exists?

Comment: Sure: `CASE x WHEN 'ID12 - Test0' THEN 'Test0' WHEN 'ID13 - Test-Part1' THEN 'Test-Part1' ... ELSE x END`. However, I *assume* that you want to implement a more general rule. If that is the case, please describe the rule in your question.

Comment: Use charindex with a case statement and the like clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table with such rows then:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(string,2) = 'ID' THEN SUBSTRING(string,CHARINDEX('-',string)+2,LEN(string))
            ELSE string END
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Can you A a Q whish On hold & unclear ?

Comment: @Sami No, now I cannot add another answer. I started to write an answer when there was no *put on hold* status on question. I presses *Post an answer* and then I saw that it was put on hold...

Comment: My pleasure! Just one question. Why you take off an accept flag on this answer? :)

Comment: sry..i clicked flag wrongly......